# How to set default ContextMenu style to EditText?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme, android-contextmenu

I have a problem with EditText's ContextMenu's **style**.
I created new Dialog:

```
Dialog newServerDialog = new Dialog(getContext(), R.style.CustomDialogStyleServerDetails);

newServerDialog.setContentView(newServerDialogLayout);
newServerDialog.setTitle(R.string.server_details_new_title_text);
newServerDialog.getWindow().setLayout(
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newServerDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Here is *CustomDialogStyleServerDetails* style:

```
<style name="CustomDialogStyleServerDetails" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/server_details_background_repeat</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>
```

And *DialogWindowTitle* style

```
<style name="DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/customDialogTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/server_details_title_background_repeat</item>
</style>
```

Dialog looks like I want: (sorry, but I can not post an image yet)

[Dialog.png](http://imageshack.us/f/856/20120924114942.png/)

But EditText's ContextMenu takes style from my dialog

[EditText's ContextMenu.png](http://imageshack.us/f/837/20120924114953.png/)

Is there any way, how to set default style to ContextMenu?
I did not find any fix for this issue.
All help will be appreciated!
Thank you.

EDIT: Solution for me: creating a custom class (called DialogServer) which extends Dialog.
EDIT #2: Nope, looks like that is not the right solution.
I tried this constructor:

```
public DialogServer(Context context, int theme)
```

and the problem remains

With this constructor:

```
public DialogServer(Context context)
```

contextmenu's style is ok, but style of the dialog is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Custom Theme Wrapper

```
 ContextThemeWrapper mTheme = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
        R.style.CustomDialogStyleServerDetails);
```

The code snippet is  :-

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
        LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

ContextThemeWrapper mTheme = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
        R.style.CustomDialogStyleServerDetails);

mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT_FILE, null);


mDialog = new Dialog(mTheme);
mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mDialog.setContentView(this.mView);
mDialog.show();
```

Hope the explanation was useful....

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not working. ContextMenu's style is still wrong. I tried to create custom Dialog class which extends Dialog, but the problem remains (see edited question).